# How do I have the setup program in Visual studio install to more than one directory?

Tags: setup-project, visual-studio-2022

I've seen some similar questions asked here, but they don't seem to answer my specific question.
Visual Studio 2020 - Setup project.
My setup project currently installs files to the destination folder, we'll call it Dir.AI. All my setup's output goes there. This works fine. But I would also like my setup program to install the exact same files to Dir.LS, and Dir.TC. I.e.,
Setup should install all files to all three of:

```
\Dir.AI
\Dir.LS
\Dir.TC
```

I would prefer to keep this to a single install package (setup.exe and setup.msi).
Is this supported?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks Hans, I guess. But the above is not an XY problem at all.
The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. 
I did no such thing. I asked HOW to have a single installer install into three directories.

Comment: I appreciate this is an older question but I see it just garnered an answer. Since Hans didn't comment further - wanting or needing to install 3 identical copies of your files into a target system is *odd*. *Something* caused you to think it was a reasonable way to *solve an unstated problem*. So to put it more bluntly, why do you think installing 3 copies of your application files is the right thing to do?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I run a game server. Each 'server' (called a shard) needs its own account data, state data, etc. (separate directories.) The server install image is identical for each of my three shards. to launch a different shard, you need only supply different command line switches.

Comment: FWIW, I run:
Login Server
Angel Island Server
Angel Island Test Center
These are my three shards.
I'm considering adding a 4th shard - Mortalis (a mortals-only shard)
Currently, I install into the main Angel Island shard, but then have to run a batch file to copy the updated components to the other folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so take a look at this image : [image: Types of Folder where you can install your targeted files]

Here you have multiple options to choose from if none of these fancy you look at the bottom most "Custom Folder" Here you can set your custom directory and you can create as many as you want. To set its directory location you can do that by first clicking it and then accessing its property window which will be displayed on left bottom side of visual studio panel as shown below
[image: Properties Panel]

Once that's done simply drop all your files which are in application folder same as in this custom folder and you are good to go.

To access this panel view File system and right click on the top "File System on Target Machine".

Comment: Thank you @MoonLight
I think will do it :)

Comment: no problem. happy building.